# Postgres: Select users with several accounts

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to find users from my db that have more then one account. Each user has lastname and firstname attribute.

How can I list all users that have the same equal firstname and lastname?

EXAMPLE DATA

```
id | lastname   | firstname
1  | Smith      | John
2  | Smith      | John
3  | McDonald   | Ronald
```

I need to make select that will output:

```
lastname | firstname | number_of_accounts
Smith    | John      | 2
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count(*)` and `group by:`

```
select lastname, firstname, count(*)
from my_table
group by lastname, firstname;

 lastname | firstname | count 
----------+-----------+-------
 McDonald | Ronald    |     1
 Smith    | John      |     2
(2 rows)
```

You can filter the results with `having` clause:

```
select lastname, firstname, count(*)
from my_table
group by lastname, firstname
having count(*) > 1;

 lastname | firstname | count 
----------+-----------+-------
 Smith    | John      |     2
(1 row)
```